# Unable to display or add View from android to React-Native

Tags: android, react-native

I have an ImageButton in which I want to add to the Layout. This is written in Java.

```
 ViewGroup rootLayout = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
            captureToolBar = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar, null);
            rootLayout.addView(captureToolBar);
            captureToolList.add(captureToolBar);
            captureActivity.add(activity);
            rootLayout.invalidate();
```

After which I then include it to React-Native using android gradle.

However, after running it on React-Native, the layout is shown as this:
[image]

As you can see the ImageButton is there but not shown. I think maybe it's got to do with not being inside a View? If so how can I get it to show on React-Native?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had to do the XML file of the ImageButton.

The xml had

```
app:srcCompat="image location"
```

In which React Native didn't like

So i changed that to

```
   android:src = "image location"
```

Then the image showed.